# Orientation in iPhone?

Tags: iphone-sdk-4.1

In my application, I use Orientation, I have to change the size of the controls according to the orientation. I have used a flag and according to that flag I change the size of the controls. But my doubt is, will this orientation affect every time, when user rotates the phone?

Answer (score 0):

I think, better you use 
`view.autoresizingMask` instead of changing the view sizes wrt orientation. Otherwise, it will change the size, but still, the orientation-size code will be called again n again.